# Trigger one of two links when a certain key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, keyboard-events

I want to trigger the first link with the <kbd>E</kbd> key or the second link with the <kbd>R</kbd> key. I'd like to avoid having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the navigation.

This is what I've tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    
    if (e.keyCode == 76) {
      $("div:first-of-type a").focus();
      $("div:nth-of-type(2n) a").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google (E)</a>
  <a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube (R)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. You cannot nest a tags.

Comment: Okey ... so do I put two links and trigger them with keys ?

Comment: Where is your key event code? What have you tried?

Comment: Something like this $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
        $("div:first-of-type a").focus();
  $("div:nth-of-type(2n) a").focus();
    }
  });
});

Comment: You have an extra `</a>` tag in your code.

Comment: Removed but don't know how it will affect

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple script:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 69) { // e
        $("#yourLink1").click();
    }
});

$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 82) { // r
        $("#yourLink2").click();
    }
});
```

You can find more KeyCodes here: https://keycode.info/

I also recommend giving your links [IDs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp):

```html
<div class="test">
    <a id="yourLink1" href="http://google.com"></a>
    <a id="yourLink2" href="http://youtube.com"></a>
    <img src="https://www.hugochaume.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-codepen.png">
</div>
```

### Update:

Since the `.which` and `.keyCode` methods are actually considered deprecated, I would recommend using `.code`:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.code == "KeyE") { // e
        $("#yourLink1").click();
    }
    if (e.code == "KeyR") { // r
        $("#yourLink2").click();
    }
});
```

(Thanks to [Danziger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger) for proposing this)

Comment: I added ID for both links ( #yourLink1 & #yourLink2 ) but apparently not working.

Comment: You changed it, and used my JavaScript above?

Comment: Yes you can check it yourself https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/rNejGMG

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Because the codepen you sent me doesn't have JQuery enabled, an codepen doesn't support redirects...

Comment: I added the jquery script in the beginning but still not working.

Comment: Here is a fiddle link with Jquery https://jsfiddle.net/uof0mnv5/1/

Comment: Just replace the `click()` functions with: `document.location = "(link here)"`

Comment: `e.which` is deprecated. You should be using `e.code` instead. Also, take a look at this other tool to get JS KeyBoard events' properties: https://keyjs.dev

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give either anchor the focus and try to programmatically click it, just directly navigate to the `href` of the desired link.

Also, you are missing a closing quote after `class="test`.

By the way "e" and "r" are 69 and 82 (respectively), not 76.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 69) { 
      location.href = "https://youtube.com";
      alert("Going to YouTube"); // Just for testing
    } else if(e.keyCode == 82) {
      location.href = "https://example.com";
      alert("Going to Example");  // Just for testing
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <a href="https://youtube.com">
    <img src="https://www.hugochaume.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-codepen.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The second "a:nth-of-type(2)").href" doesn't work, the first one does.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo There was a missing quote in the `div` element which was causing that problem. Fixed now.

Comment: Yes it's working, but I think you misunderstood. I want both links on the same image, but trigger one of them if a key is pressed !

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Updated the answer. All that you'd do then is just remove the second link and hard code the URLs that you should be taken to instead of trying to get them from the links.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. You should be using `e.code` instead. Also, duplicating `href` in the JS code doesn't look too flexible, as the HTML content might actually be dynamic.

Comment: @Danziger Both good points, but neither go to the heart of the question. I used `keyCode` because that's what the OP is using and not the source of the problem. The hard-coding of the URLs  is just a means to show how the proposed question could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add `id`s to both links so that you can grab them from the JS and then update `window.location` with their `href` value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind('keydown', (e) => {
    const link = document.getElementById(`link${ e.key.toUpperCase() }`);
    
    if (link) {
      console.log(`Should redirect to ${ link.href }...`);
      location.href = link.href;
    } else {
      console.log(`No link for key = ${ e.key }.`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

kbd {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 66px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <a href="http://google.com" id="linkE">Google <kbd>E</kbd></a>  
  <a href="http://youtube.com" id="linkR">YouTube <kbd>R</kbd></a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add `id`s, you can use jQuery's [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to grab the right link based on its position:

```js
$test = $('.test');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind('keydown', (e) => {
    const key = e.key.toUpperCase();
    
    if (key !== 'E' && key !== 'R') {
      console.log(`No link for key = ${ e.key }.`, e.code);
      return;
    }
    
    const link = $test.children().eq(key === 'E' ? 0 : 1);
        
    if (link) {
      console.log(`Should redirect to ${ link.attr('href') }...`);
      // location.href = link.href;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

kbd {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 66px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google <kbd>E</kbd></a>  
  <a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube <kbd>R</kbd></a>
</div>
```